# document with relid in url not displayed

Tags: pdf, url, zend-framework

On my ZF-1 based website I have a document with the name erelid.pdf (erelid is member of honour in Dutch) which won't be displayed. When I change the name of the document, it's displayed fine.

So:

- http://www.example.com/public/documents/erelid.pdf is not displayed. Got redirected to some kind of 404-page.
- I change the name of the document in erelip.pdf
  http://www.expample.com/public/documents/erelip.pdf is displayed

I don't understand what goes wrong. Can't find a clue in the logging as well.

Is relid some kind of reserved word?

Comment: I think that is a cache problem. Try a different browser or clear cache.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your reaction, but it's not a cache issue. I checked in different browsers after clearing the cache. Only when the name of the document contains "relid", it is not displayed...

Comment: Files in `public/` typically are not routed through ZF. You say you see "some kind of 404 page" - is that a ZF 404 page, or an Apache one? If you could edit your question to include the relevant logs that would be helpful too.